# Does anyone know if it's 'normal' that you can't defrag an Outlook .ost file?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, performance, defragment

I've tried defragmenting my hard disk to see if Outlook performance improves. The .ost file shows 1000+ fragments but even after a post-defragmentation restart - never launching Outlook - it still shows that the file hasn't actually been defragmented.

Could this be contributing to slower Outlook performance? Any ideas how I can get the .ost file defragmented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it 'normal'? Yes.

Can you defragment them?  Yes, but you need an extra MS utility called "Contig" (short for Contiguous).

You can [get Contig from here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx).

Tutorial ([from here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7201286_defragment-ost-file.html)):

> 1. Close the Outlook program.
> 2. Click the "Start" button, then click the "Search" box. Type "*.ost"
>    in the "Search" box and press the
>    "Enter" key. Right-click the "OST"
>    file displayed in the search results
>    and click "Properties" in the menu
>    that appears.
> 3. Note the path to the "OST" file that is displayed in the "Properties"
>    window that appears.
> 4. Click the "Start" button, then click "Programs." Click "Accessories"
>    and then right-click on the command
>    line icon. Click "Run as
>    Administrator" in the menu that
>    appears.
> 5. Type "cd c:\path_to_contig," substituting "c:\path_to_contig" with
>    the actual path and directory where
>    the Contig utility is located, then
>    press the "Enter" key.
> 6. Type "contig --v path_to_ost/filename.ost,"
>    substituting
>    "path_to_ost/filename.ost" with the
>    actual path and name for the "OST"
>    file, then press the "Enter" key.
> 7. Wait while the Contig utility processes the "OST" file. When the
>    command line output confirms that the
>    defrag operation has completed, you
>    can start Outlook.

More info [here](http://www.blankmanblog.com/uncategorized/ost-performance-slow-defrag-it/).

Hope that helps...